# How to perform return key action in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to perform the return key action without pressing the keyboard.
Is it possible to perform this action? It's been a week and I am not able to find anything that can help me.

Comment: Needs more clarification..! kindly provide what did you do so far, and..what you want to achieve

Comment: I have developed an app that opens a pre-installed app in my device. With that i can interact using my keyboard. But i want to automate that task and press the keys automatically for me.